# GitHub Desktop keeps opening every time I type in Android Studio

Tags: android, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

It's extremely irritating. If I exit out of GitHub Desktop, it'll open right back up as soon as I type a character in my project and block my view. I tried looking for this issue on Google, but I can't find anyone with the same problem. I am fairly new with Android and very new with GitHub, so this is possibly a silly error on my part, but it is driving me crazy. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking in the VCS menu in the Android Studio menus and disabling GitHub integration?

Comment: @shanem Might be a stupid question, but how do you disable GitHub integration? And then how would you re-enable it?

Comment: I disabled the Github plugin. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you figured it out.